# Variables inserted into URL not showing in address bar

Tags: c#, asp.net, telerik

I have a method being used on a button to redirect to a different page. There are several variables that are inserted into the URL to help navigate to what the user wants to see. It works well, except for the fact that the variables do not show up in the address bar.

Upon button click and redirect to the next page the url looks like: `/Beta.aspx/?year=&track=&event=&car=27&session`

How can I get my variables to show up in the address bar? Below is the code being used for the button click.

```
protected void btnConfirm_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

    string url = string.Format("Beta.aspx/?year={0}&track={1}&event={2}&car=27&session{3}",hidYear.Value, hidTrack.Value, hidEvent.Value, hidSession.Value);
    Response.Redirect(url);
}
```

Button Setup

```
<telerik:RadImageButton ID="RadImageButton2" runat="server" Skin="Material" Text="27" OnClick="btnConfirm_Click">
</telerik:RadImageButton>
```

Form Tag

```
<form id="form1" runat="server" class="SmallFont">
```

Hidden Fields

```
<asp:HiddenField runat="server" ID="hidYear" />
<asp:HiddenField runat="server" ID="hidTrack" />
<asp:HiddenField runat="server" ID="hidEvent" />
<asp:HiddenField runat="server" ID="hidSession" />
```

Comment: do you have the `runat="server"` on the hidden `<input>` fields?

Comment: also you may have a typo on the first `hidTrack.Value`, it should probably be `hidYear.Value`

Comment: @Xiaoy312 good catch :P, it is indeed `runat="server"`

Comment: Put a breakpoint in the code and verify that all those variables actually have values. My guess is that they don't.

Comment: @LasseV.Karlsen When clicking the button it takes me to the correct page as if the variables were there, the displayed URL is just not what it should be for the page that it navigates to.

Comment: Try replacing the RadImageButton with standard asp:Button and see if that works.

Comment: @ViniciusRocha just tried, a regular button behaves the same!

Comment: Code is working fine. Either the HiddenFields are empty on PostBack or some url rewriting is going on.

Comment: @VDWWD The button and all of the fields exists on `Default2.aspx`. Clicking the button redirects to `Beta.aspx`. Could it be an issue where the hidden fields are blank in `Beta.aspx`?

Comment: The code that you pasted works just fine for me. Can you share a sample project that reproduces the issue?

Comment: @ViniciusRocha The code runs for me as well. The variables do not make it into the URL. Are you saying that when you run it with sample data/variables that they show up in the URL?

Comment: @MaxB, no the hidden fields must be on the page doing the redirect. Are you perhaps emptying the `HiddenField` in `Page_Load` without an `IsPostBack` check? `protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e) { hidYear.Value = ""; }` must be `protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e) { if (!IsPostBack) { hidYear.Value = ""; } }`

Answer (score 4):

When RadImageButton2 is clicked, the page is *posted back* to the server for processing. This process is called ASP.NET postback mechanism and IsPostback is normally used on page_load event to detect if the page is getting generated due to postback requested by a control on the page, or if the page is getting loaded for the first time. This is important for the case when values of the controls are set programmatically and should not be overwritten when page was posted back.

See this snippet:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    hidYear.Value = "";
    hidTrack.Value = "";
    hidEvent.Value = "";
    hidSession.Value = ""; 
}

protected void Init_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    hidYear.Value = "2020";
    hidTrack.Value = "1";
    hidEvent.Value = "2";
    hidSession.Value = "0123456789";
}

protected void btnConfirm_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string url = string.Format("Beta.aspx/?year={0}&track={1}&event={2}&car=27&session{3}", 
       hidYear.Value, hidTrack.Value, hidEvent.Value, hidSession.Value);
    Response.Redirect(url);
}
```

It all will run well, but values on the redirect will be always "" because Page_Load() is called with every postback. However, with the following little change the values on redirect will be not changed and populated to the state before form submit:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (!IsPostBack) { 
       hidYear.Value = "";
       hidTrack.Value = "";
       hidEvent.Value = "";
       hidSession.Value = "";
    }
}
```

Note, actual values of controls can be found by looking at the source of the page

[image]

Bottom line here: hidden fields should have values when looking at the source before clicking on RadImageButton2 and Page_Load() should not call any code that changes those values, or should check for `if (!IsPostBack)`.

P.S.

Simple redirect does not required server code and can be done with client script, example:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
   function PageRedirect() {
       window.location.href = "Beta.aspx/?year="
           + document.getElementById('<%=hidYear.ClientID%>').value
           + "&track=" + document.getElementById('<%=hidTrack.ClientID%>').value
           + "&event=" + document.getElementById('<%=hidEvent.ClientID%>').value
           + "&car=27&session" + document.getElementById('<%=hidSession.ClientID%>').value;
   }
 </script>

<asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Client Redirect" 
     OnClientClick="PageRedirect();return false;" />
```

Answer (score 0):

You're saying that it does work. That means that the variables are being passed.
There is a chance that the solution is really, really simple.

Variables don't show up in the address bar until you click on it. Try clicking on the URL in your address bar, it will select the URL and the variables will show. If not, only then it has to do something with the code.

Answer (score 0):

Ahh, there's the mistake Bro. there isn't any value for these hidden controls

```
<asp:HiddenField runat="server" ID="hidYear" />
<asp:HiddenField runat="server" ID="hidTrack" />
<asp:HiddenField runat="server" ID="hidEvent" />
<asp:HiddenField runat="server" ID="hidSession" />
```

either you can add value in the ASPX page as

```
<asp:HiddenField runat="server" ID="hidYear" Value="1234"/>
<asp:HiddenField runat="server" ID="hidTrack" Value="4321" />
<asp:HiddenField runat="server" ID="hidEvent" Value="1234" />
<asp:HiddenField runat="server" ID="hidSession" Value="2405"/>
```

or as mentioned by user https://stackoverflow.com/users/2316116/user2316116 you can use

```
hidYear.Value = "2020";
hidTrack.Value = "1";
hidEvent.Value = "2";
hidSession.Value = "0123456789";
```

the reason the value is not being displayed in the URL is simply that there isn't a value that can be displayed.

make sure to check for empty values if you're taking inputs from the user in future applications.

Answer (score -1):

You should not have '/' between 'beta.aspx' and '?'. Try removing that extra slash and see if that resolves your issue.

Comment: @MaxB you're saying it works fine, have you made sure that in the Beta.aspx you are actually receiving the values? it seems to me that the hid*.value is actually empty.

Comment: Yeah I am receiving the values and it is navigating to the correct page.

Comment: Can u post the html of the page?

Comment: of the entire page or just the button? The entire page is a lot of code.

Comment: the button, the hidden fields and the form tags if possible.

Comment: Care to share the rest? hidden fields and form tag?

Comment: Apologies, it is all there now

Comment: @MaxB everything looks normal as far as the form. Can you add the onload function in the Beta page?